# text not visible on a window Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am doing a mini project on solar system using openGL.I am trying to create two windows ,the first one shows my name,college name and other details and the second one will show the solar system.My second screen is working perfectly fine ,but i am not able to print any text on my first screen.Below is the code,can anyone check my code and tell me where's the error.

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>


static int m=0,M=0,v=0,V=0,E=0,e=0,r=0,R=0,j=0,J=0,s=0,S=0,U=0,u=0,n=0,N=0,X=0,z=0,B=0,b=0,c=0;
static GLint axis=2;
int isMainScreen=1;

GLfloat diffuseMaterial[4]={0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0};

/*initialize material property,light soure,lighting model,and depth buffer*/
void drawString1(float x, float y, float z, char * string) {
    char * c;
    glRasterPos3f(x, y, z);
    for (c = string; * c != '\0'; c++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, * c);
    }
}

void myinit(void)
{   
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLfloat mat_specular[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
    GLfloat light_position[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0};

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,diffuseMaterial);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,mat_specular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,25.0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_position);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void display(void)
{
    GLfloat position[]={0.0,0.0,1.5,1.0};
    glColor3f(1.0,0.5,0.0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((GLfloat)z,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,position);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glutSolidSphere(0.8,40,16); /*draw sun*/
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,position);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColor3f(1.5,0.5,0.0);
    glutSolidTorus(0.2,0.9,6,20);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((GLfloat)M,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(1.5,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)m,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.2,20,8); /*draw smaller planet mercury*/
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((GLfloat)V,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(2.0,0.0,1.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)v,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(7.5,9.5,1.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.2,20,8); /*draw smaller plant venus*/
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((GLfloat)E,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(3.5,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)e,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.1,6.5,2.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.2,20,8); /*draw smaller plant earth*/
    glRotatef((GLfloat)X,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.3,0.2,0.0);
    glColor3f(4.3,3.5,8.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.1,20,14); /*draw moon*/
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((GLfloat)R,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(5.0,0.0,3.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)r,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.2,0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.2,20,8); /*draw smaller planet mars*/
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((GLfloat)J,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(-2.5,0.0,1.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)j,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.9,0.7,0.3);
    glutSolidSphere(0.2,20,8);/*draw smaller planet Jupiter*/
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef((GLfloat)S,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(-5.0,0.0,0.0);
    gluLookAt(0.0,10.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)s,0.0,0.0,5.0);
    glColor3f(4.5,0.5,0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.5,20,16); /*draw smaller plant Saturn*/
    int i=0;
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for(i=0;i<=360;i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(sin(i*3.1416/180)*0.5,cos(i*3.1416/180)*0.5,0);
        glVertex3f(sin(i*3.1416/180)*0.7,cos(i*3.1416/180)*0.7,0);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef ((GLfloat) U, 0.0, 1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef (-6.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    gluLookAt (10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 1.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat) u, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0);
    glColor3f( 1.2, 0.6,0.2);
    glutSolidSphere (0.5, 20, 16); /* draw smaller planet Uranus*/
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for(i=0; i<=360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(sin(i*3.1416/180)*0.5,cos(i*3.1416/180)*0.5, 0);
        glVertex3f(sin(i*3.1416/180)*0.7, cos(i*3.1416/180)*0.7,0);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef ((GLfloat) N,0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef (-8.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef ((GLfloat) n, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 2.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.4, 20, 8);
    glPopMatrix();/* draw smaller planet Neptune */
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef ((GLfloat) c, 6.0, -14.0,-6.0);
    glTranslatef (5.0,3.0,-1.0);
    glScalef(0.60,0.0,2.5);
    glColor3f (7.5, 9.5, 2.0);
    glutSolidSphere (0.2, 12, 6);
    glPopMatrix();/*draw comet*/
    //to put the stars as a background
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0,-2.0,0.0);
    gluLookAt(0.0,10.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)b,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glScalef(200.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(4.3,3.5,1.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.04,20,8);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0,2.0,0.0);
    gluLookAt(0.0,10.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)b,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glScalef(200.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(4.3,3.5,1.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.04,20,8);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(8.7,9.0,0.0);
    gluLookAt(0.0,10.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)b,1.0,7.0,5.0);
    glColor3f(4.3,3.5,1.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.04,20,8);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w,int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w,(GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0,(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h,1.0,20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
    printf("%d", key);
    switch(key)
    {
        case 'z':
            z=(z+50)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'm':
            m=(m+3)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'M':
            M=(M+12)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'v':
            v=(v+2)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'V':
            V=(V+10)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'e':
            e=(e+5)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'E':
            E=(E+8)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'r':
            r=(r+6)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'R':
            R=(R+6)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'j':
            j=(j+10)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'J':
            J=(J+4)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 's':
            s=(s+9)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'S':
            S=(S+3)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'u':
            u=(u+8)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'U':
            U=(U+2)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'n':
            n=(n+7)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'N':
            N=(N+1)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'b':
            b=(b+10)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'c':
            c=(c+1)%360;
            b=(b+10)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'X':
            X=(X+5)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'a':
            z=(z+50)%360;
            b=(b+10)%360;
            m=(m+3)%360;
            v=(v+2)%360;
            e=(e+5)%360;
            r=(r+6)%360;
            j=(j+10)%360;
            s=(s+9)%360;
            u=(u+8)%360;
            n=(n+7)%360;
            c=(c+1)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
         case 'A':
            z=(z+50)%360;
            b=(b+10)%360;
            M=(M+12)%360;
            V=(V+10)%360;
            E=(E+8)%360;
            R=(R+6)%360;
            J=(J+4)%360;
            S=(S+3)%360;
            U=(U+2)%360;
            N=(N+1)%360;
            c=(c+1)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
         case 'B':
            z=(z+50)%360;
            b=(b+10)%360;
            c=(c+1)%360;
            m=(m+3)%360;
            M=(M+12)%360;
            v=(v+2)%360;
            V=(V+10)%360;
            e=(e+5)%360;
            E=(E+8)%360;
            r=(r+6)%360;
            R=(R+6)%360;
            j=(j+10)%360;
            J=(J+4)%360;
            s=(s+9)%360;
            S=(S+3)%360;
            u=(u+8)%360;
            U=(U+2)%360;
            n=(n+7)%360;
            N=(N+1)%360;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 13:
            isMainScreen = 0;
            break;
        case 27:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void frontscreen(void)
{
     glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
     drawString1(0.5,0.5,0.0,"MVJ College of Engineering");
     glColor3f(0.7,0,1);
     drawString1(120,400,0.0,"DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING");
     glColor3f(1,0.5,0);
     drawString1(210.0, 300.0,0.0,"A MINI PROJECT ON");
     glColor3f(1,0,0);
     drawString1(220,270,0.0,"PROJECT TITLE");
     glColor3f(1,0.5,0);
     drawString1(20,50,0.0,"BY:");
     glColor3f(0.5,0,0.5);
     drawString1(10,40,0.0,"NAME FIRST           (USN)");
     drawString1(10,34,0.0,"NAME SECOND         (USN)");
     glColor3f(1,0.5,0);
     drawString1(68,50,0.0,"GUIDES:");
     glColor3f(0.5,0.2,0.2);
     drawString1(63,40,0.0,"GUIDE NAME FIRST");
     drawString1(63,34,0.0,"GUIDE NAME SECOND");
     glColor3f(1,0.1,1);
     drawString1(32,10,0.0,"PRESS ENTER TO START");
     glFlush();
     glutPostRedisplay();
}


void mouse(int btn ,int state,int x,int y)
{
    if(btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        z=(z+50)%360;
        b=(b+10)%360;
        c=(c+1)%360;
        m=(m+3)%360;M=(M+12)%360;
        v=(v+2)%360;V=(V+10)%360;
        e=(e+5)%360;E=(E+8)%360;
        r=(r+6)%360;R=(R+6)%360;
        j=(j+10)%360;J=(J+4)%360;
        s=(s+9)%360;S=(S+3)%360;
        u=(u+8)%360;U=(U+2)%360;
        n=(n+7)%360;N=(N+1)%360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    if(btn==GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        z=(z+50)%360;
        b=(b+10)%360;
        c=(c+1)%360;
        m=(m+3)%360;M=(M+12)%360;
        v=(v-2)%360;V=(V-10)%360;
        e=(e+5)%360;E=(E+8)%360;
        r=(r-6)%360;R=(R-6)%360;
        j=(j+10)%360;J=(J+4)%360;
        s=(s-9)%360;S=(S-3)%360;
        u=(u+8)%360;U=(U+2)%360;
        n=(n-7)%360;N=(N-1)%360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    if(btn==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        z=(z-50)%360;
        b=(b-10)%360;
        c=(c+1)%360;
        m=(m-3)%360;M=(M-12)%360;
        v=(v-2)%360;V=(V-10)%360;
        e=(e-5)%360;E=(E-8)%360;
        r=(r-6)%360;R=(R-6)%360;
        j=(j-10)%360;J=(J-4)%360;
        s=(s-9)%360;S=(S-3)%360;
        u=(u-8)%360;U=(U-2)%360;
        n=(n-7)%360;N=(N-1)%360;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void mydisplay() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (isMainScreen) {
        frontscreen();  
    } else {
        display();
    }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("planets amidst stars");
    myinit();
    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    //glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboardFunc);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone correct the error?

Comment: Whoever checks this code .... good luck!

Comment: We don't need everything from your original program - you should [edit] to reduce your code to the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, with no extraneous parts that don't contribute to that demonstration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you specified in [`glutInitDisplayMode`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html), you are using double buffering (`GLUT_DOUBLE`):

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
```

This causes that you have to call [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) to swaps the buffers of the current window at the end of the rendering ([`glFlush`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFlush.xml) is not sufficient).

Further, I recommend to setup an orthographic projection, which maps the viewspace 1:1 to window coordinates.
Use [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) for this and use [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) to switch between the projection matrix stack and the modelview matrix stack.

Change the code in the function `frontscreen` like this:

```
double vp_width = 1024.0; // update by reshape
double vp_height = 600.0; // update by reshape

void frontscreen(void)
{
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, vp_width, vp_height, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    .....

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();   // <----- glutSwapBuffers insted of glFlush
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked

Comment: initially i just replaced glFlush() with glutswapbuffers() and it was working(i had to change the coordinates).Now i added those glmatrixmode..... ,now coordinates are working fine but when i press enter it is changing the window but that screen remains blank whereas it is supposed to show the display function code

Comment: Yeah,it's working now.Thanks

Comment: One more doubt related to this code,when i am running this code on mac ,then the rotation of the planets and comet revolution speed becomes very low,but on windows system it works fine,and there's a case in the code,where if i press b then stars give the glowing effect but that effect doesn't work on mac,so can you tell me if i have to include any libraries or any other statement?